# Create a new column based on a dictionary using R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr

For the following dataframe `d`, I'm trying to create a new column by replacing `col1` using a dictionary `dict_to_replace`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

d <- data.frame(col1 = c("AA", "AG", "AC", "AA"), col2 = c(NA, "GG", "GG", "GC"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
dict_to_replace <- c('AA'='a', 'AG'='b')

d %>% 
  mutate(
    col3 = str_replace_all(col1, pattern = dict_to_replace)
  )
```

Out:

```
  col1 col2 col3
1   AA <NA>    a
2   AG   GG    b
3   AC   GG   AC
4   AA   GC    a
```

But I expected if the values in `col1` is not in the key of `dict_to_replace`, then replace by `NA` instead of values in `col1`, which means the expected result will like this:

```
  col1 col2 col3
1   AA <NA>    a
2   AG   GG    b
3   AC   GG  <NA>
4   AA   GC    a
```

How could I achieve that in pipe (%>%) using R? Thanks.

Comment: It's not a pipe, but `dict_to_replace[d$col1]` would do it via indexing. I guess you could stuff it in a pipe - `d %>% mutate(col3 = dict_to_replace[col1] )`

Comment: Thanks, it works. BTW, maybe a redundant question, do you know is it possible to use `str_replace_all()` to do the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can use str_replace_all for this task. Another alternative to use is `recode` from the **dplyr** package.

```
d %>% 
  mutate(
    col3 = recode(col1, !!!dict_to_replace, .default = NA_character_)
  )
```

In here you use the bang bang operator !!! to unquote the `dict_to_replace` named vector, and the .default argument allows you to change values not matching in the col1 column. More can be found in the documentation as stated:

> .default   If supplied, ***all values not otherwise matched*** will be given
> this value. If not supplied and if the replacements are the same type
> as the original values in .x, unmatched values are not changed. If not
> supplied and if the replacements are not compatible, unmatched values
> are replaced with NA.